# How to calculate maximum value including string?

Tags: r, data.table

I want to keep the string while using .SD, max .

```
data <- data.table(id = c("a", "a", "b", "c"),
                   s1 = c(1, 3, 2, 2),
                   s2 = c(3, 1, 1, 0),
                   s3 = c(5, 3, 0, 2),
                   ta = c("ba", "bb", "cc", "dd"))

out_data <- data[, lapply(.SD, max), by=id]
```

Desired output:

```
   id s1 s2 s3 ta
1:  a  0  3  5 ba
2:  a  3  0  0 bb
3:  b  2  1  0 cc
4:  c  2  0  2 dd
```

How can I keep ta information according to id?

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I can think of is this:

```
colList <- c("s1", "s2", "s3")
out_data <- data[, (colList) := lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(x == max(x), x, 0)), by=.(id)]
```

There is no reason to specify `.SDcols` in this construction. If you were to remove the `colList` portion and simply used `.SDcols` it would remove the `ta` column altogether.

Edit: as @zx8754 correctly points out this will alter the state of data as well, as R will first execute what's to the right of the `<-` and afterwards assign it to `out_data`. You can prevent this by doing:

```
colList <- c("s1", "s2", "s3")
out_data <- copy(data)[, (colList) := lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(x == max(x), x, 0)), by=.(id)]
```

Comment: Note that `data` object is now updated, too. `identical(out_data, data) # TRUE`

Comment: Good point, edited my answer

Comment: When using `.SD` on a subset of columns, it's always faster to include `.SDcols` (at least theoretically, data this small likely won't show much significant difference). You can derive `cols` dynamically here with `cols <- names(which(sapply(data, is.numeric)))`.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the value equals to max or if it is a character:

```
data[, lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(x == max(x) | is.character(x), x, 0)), by = id]
#    id s1 s2 s3 ta
# 1:  a  0  3  5 ba
# 2:  a  3  0  0 bb
# 3:  b  2  1  0 cc
# 4:  c  2  0  2 dd
```

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` solution:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(s1:s3), ~ ifelse(.x == max(.x), max(.x), 0)))

  id       s1    s2    s3 ta   
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1 a         0     3     5 ba   
2 a         3     0     0 bb   
3 b         2     1     0 cc   
4 c         2     0     2 dd
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.

The code works fine.

However, I get a row where s1, s2, and s3 are all 0.

Is there a way to remove rows where s1, s2, s3 are all 0?

thank you.

Comment: Yes, you can add `filter(!if_all(s1:s3, ~ .x == 0))`.